# Why I can't receive messages from GCM on android device

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating an android application where I need to send gcm messages.
So far I managed to get **device id** and to sent it to my server.
Now when I'm trying to push a message from my server to my app, I receive this message : **{"multicast_id":4987023356709284342,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1430085972465424%73c650e3f9fd7ecd"}]}**, but nothing happens on the device (doesn't matter if the app is running or not).

#### Here is my relevant code:

**Manifest.xml-----------------** [AndroidManifest.xml](http://tziuka.com/code/taxi/AndroidManifest.html)
**BroadcastReceiver--------** [GcmBroadcastReceiver](http://tziuka.com/code/taxi/GcmBroadcastReceiver.html)
**IntentService----------------** [GcmIntentService](http://tziuka.com/code/taxi/GcmIntentService.html)
**Register----------------------** [GcmRegister](http://tziuka.com/code/taxi/GcmRegister.html) 
*here I am using the register class (look for '**GCM HERE**' tag)*
**LoginActivity----------------** [LoginActivity](http://tziuka.com/code/taxi/LoginActivity.html) 
*here is my android project structure*
**Structure---------------------** [structure](http://tziuka.com/code/taxi/structure.jpg)
*Server side [PHP]*
**GcmPush -------------------** [GcmPush.php](http://tziuka.com/code/taxi/GcmPush.html)
*and this is how I'm using GcmPush.php*
**SendMessage--------------** [send function](http://tziuka.com/code/taxi/send.html)

Hope someone can help me.
To point what I'm doing wrong....
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally I found...**
I put logs in **GcmReceive**, and it prints the log :), then I went to **IntentServices**, and there I found that the message has arived but notification didn't actually notify the message.
So far I didn't found yet what the problem is with my notification but, I think is something wrong with this line :

```
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,  new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
```

I am glad that the biggest problem is solved. Now I am searching arround what I'm doing wrong with Notification.

Thanks very much to everyone who tried to help...

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer the tutorial of GCM [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/). According to me you are missing the configuration file of GCM which has the APP_SERVER_URL, GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID.

Comment: I have this things... look closely in GcmRegister.  The APP_SERVER_URL is this link "http://taxi.tziuka.com/set-device_id"  and GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID the same is located in GcmRegister. I receive this from StaticThings class. However my problem is not sending device id to the server, but receiving messages from the server...( APP_SERVER_URL and  GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID are used for retrive device id... I already did that). Thank you.